# How to execute a React component received from an API response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling an API and receiving a react component (in string format) as a response.

```
const [externalComponent, setExternalComponent] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    getCompnentData();
}, []);

const getCompnentData = (): void => {
    try {
        /* here some API call and received response */
        setExternalComponent(response.data);

    } catch (exception) {
        console.log(exception);
    }
}
```

I need to render the response data as a react component under the

```
<div>{Parser(externalComponent)}</div>
```

& make it functional e.g. textbox, submit button etc.

The react component I receive as a string in response is below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { CardContainer, Button } from 'common/style';

const POC4 = () => {
 const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: 'Jack',
    lastName: 'Li',
    Email: 'test.name@test.com'
 })

const handleUpdate = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const tempFormData = {...formData};
    tempFormData[name] = value;
    setFormData(tempFormData);
}

const submitForm = () => {
    console.log(formData)
}

return (
        <CardContainer className='sm-12' style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-6">
                    <input type="text" name='firstName' className="form-control" value={formData.firstName} onChange={handleUpdate} />
                    <input type="text" name='lastName' className="form-control" value={formData.lastName} onChange={handleUpdate}/>
                    <input type="text" name='Email' className="form-control" value={formData.Email} onChange={handleUpdate}/>

                    <div className='mt-2'>
                        <Button
                            className="primary"
                            htmlType="submit"
                            loading={false}
                            onClick={submitForm}>
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </CardContainer>
  )
}

export default POC4;
```

Any suggestion, please?
Thank you.